# How to set the default Sort on a DevExpress GridView

Tags: .net, gridview, devexpress, xtragrid, gridcontrol

On .net WinForm, DevExpress's GridControl/GridView bound on a DataSet, how to specify the default sort order? The one that is used when there is no visible GridColumn with a SortOrder.

By default, I have set a sorting on the view on my hidden DateTimeStamp GridColumn. It is of course overrided by user if user click on a column.
User can "Clear Sorting" using the menu on column or by clicking on a column while pressing the Control key. When doing that, Rows are not sorted anymore (or maybe by PK?) while I would like them sorted by DateTimeStamp.

Any idea? Maybe by plugging code to be notified when user "Clear Sorting"? I can play with GridView.PopupMenuShowing and GridStringId.MenuColumnClearSorting to handle the user-click-on-menu case. But it does not handle the case of Control+click.

Has someone meet the same problem and found a (simple) solution?

Comment: Simply say: `((DataView) gridControl.DataSource).Sort = "DateTimeStamp DESC";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would sort the grid's DataSource based on the required column.  In this case, if the gridView's sorting condition is cleared by the end-user, data will be displayed in the order specified by your DataSource.

**UPDATE**
here is the code which should work for you:

```
DataView dv = yourDataTable.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "SomeField";
gridControl.DataSource = dv;
```

Also, take a look at the following MSDN article :

[DataView.Sort Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx)

Comment: My data source is a System.Data.DataTable. Unlike List<>, there is no Sort() method on dataTable (to be checked). Maybe by changing the PrimaryKey of the table, but it make a lot of changes in the existing code for so few. Will try the EndSorting event solution first.

Comment: EndSorting solution does not work. Altering the PrimaryKey solution does not work. Your solution using dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(row, position) and Remove() to maintains the rows order on each update works. I think I can create a procedure that use dataTable.Select("", "LastUpdateDate, Id") and loop over results and the original table in same time to remove row not-in-their-place and re-create it and insert it at the good position. I afraid I will have some focus problems on my cells editors after each updates. Any idea for an easier solution?

Comment: What if my DataSOurce is not a DataView, or has not?

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be easiest just to disable end-user sorting?  Or have I misunderstood your problem - i.e. do you want their sorting to be applied after your default sorting?

Comment: I want the user be able to sort the grid and have the possibility to come back to the default sort when there is no user filter. I want my filter to be applied if the user does not specify a filter.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this after `InitializeComponent();` on constructor

```
GridView1.Columns["FieldName"].SortOrder = ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add event handler on `GridView.EndSorting` event, and in that handler check if there are any columns which have `SortIndex >= 0`. If there are not, you could set your own sorting.

Comment: It does not works: GridView.EndSorting is not raised on "Clear Sorting" :(

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer in Devexpress support center [How to sort GridView multiple columns programmatically?](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t473657/how-to-sort-gridview-multiple-columns-programmatically)

The following code can be used for this purpose:

```
<your GridView>.SortInfo.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumnSortInfo[] {  
       new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumnSortInfo(<your first GridColumn>, DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending),  
       new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumnSortInfo(<your second GridColumn>, DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending)});
```

More details can be found at [Sorting in Code](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/692/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/sorting/sorting-in-code)

Answer (score -3):

GridControl.SortBy(DateTimeStampColumn, ColumnSortOrder.Descending);